# .Net 4.5 and Task.Yield vs Task.Delay as an alternative to DoEvents? Which to use?

Tags: delay, .net-4.5, yield, doevents, async-await

I have been reading up on the async/await syntax introduced in .Net 4.5 and getting a feel of it.

I have found simple samples where Task.Yield is the way to go rather than Application.DoEvents. I tried one of the samples (filling in the blanks)

Code on Form1 with 1 button:

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        list.Add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
        Process(list[i]);
        await Task.Yield();
        //await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}

public static void Process(int i) {
    Debug.WriteLine(i);
}
```

However, running this code, the UI thread is blocked or I believe it is blocked as I can not move the window while the code runs. If I comment out the Task.Yield() and use the Task.Delay(1) line instead, the GUI is responsive.

So have I misunderstood something here? I know using DoEvents and the like is bad practice, but I have some legacy code I am responsible for that uses this, and I aim to replace it with Yield as it is the best choice. But first I need to get warm with async/await.

Comment: It is explicit in the MSDN Library article for Task.Yield: `For this reason, do not rely on await Task.Yield(); to keep a UI responsive.`

Comment: Ok. Bad samples out on the net then on misc Blogs.

Comment: This is so weird. To the best of my knowledge yield should first just execute everything on ui event loop and then resume in the current context. An eye opener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` doesn't magically make your code good. `Yield` is not a direct replacement for `DoEvents` (which is evil). It will take some work to change the alignment of your code.

As long as you don't need the UI context, you can just push your work off to the threadpool:

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  await Task.Run(() => {
    var list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      list.Add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
      Process(list[i]);
    }
  });
}
```

Alternatively, you can consider breaking up the UI-specific parts either using `IProgress<T>` or using `Task.Run` for the non-UI work:

```
public async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var list = new List<int>();
  await Task.Run(() => {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      list.Add(i);
    }
  });

  for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    await ProcessAsync(list[i]);
  }
}

public static async Task ProcessAsync(int i) {
  await Task.Run(() => { ... }); // background
  myUi.Text = i.ToString() + " working"; // ui
  await Task.Run(() => { ... }); // more background
  myUi.Text = i.ToString() + " complete"; // ui
}
```

Comment: Yes. I am allready very async-minded doing it with my own async library (pre .net 4.5). But the samples I found when reading up on async/await showed just the click event loop with Task.Yield supposedly yielding to the UI thread. But testing out to get the feel of it shows me that actually does not work. So the samples on the net are either wrong or I did something wrong with my code there. Delay works. Yield does not.

Comment: `Yield` *will* yield to the UI event loop. But it schedules its own continuation first. So it's up to the event loop whether the continuation gets executed first or other UI events. E.g., `GetMessage` [defines a priority for the messages it retrieves from the UI loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx), one that probably won't play well with `Yield`.

Comment: So one can not trust Yield yo behave the right way to replace the DoEvents. Delay still works tho. But is Delay better to use than DoEvents?

Comment: It's still a hack. You *could* just leave `DoEvents` in; there's no *good* replacement for it short of refactoring.

Comment: As for .Net 4.5 there is now a [Dispatcher.Yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh965189(v=vs.110).aspx) static method that works as expected unlike Task.Yield